# Make scala ignore multiple quotes in input

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I make scala ignore the quotes inside of a String?

e.g.

```
val line1 = "<row Id="85" PostTypeId="1""
```

I want `<row Id="85" PostTypeId="1"` to be considered as a single string. However scala outputs error thinking that  `"<row Id="` is a string and everything after it is not related

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val line1 = """<row Id="85" PostTypeId="1""""
```

Note those triple quotes (`"""blahblah"""`) - to parse the string without escaping.